# MySQL testing after changes

Tags: mysql, testing

Our database contains tables with UTF8 and Latin1 charsets.  We recently updated the charset to 3 tables from Latin1 to UTF8 to improve the performance of a slow running query.  The next day, we had issues where the database was extremely slow.   We reverted the changes and the database worked fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions for testing how these changes will impact our queries?  We have thousands of queries so it's impossible to test each one.  I'd like to put a process in place where we do standard testing after any type of database changes in order to minimize the risk of having performance issues or outages.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you do the update?  There is one "correct" way and several "incorrect ways".

Comment: Show us one query, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT HEX(col)...` to confirm that the data is stored "correctly".